# If $X$ is quasi-projective but the scheme $\tilde{X}$ is affine, is $X$ necessarily affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

I'm curious if the following works as a criterion to determine when a quasi-projective variety is actually affine.

If $X$ is a quasi-projective variety, and the scheme $\tilde{X}$ is affine, does this necessarily imply that $X$ is an affine variety?

Comment: To what does $\tilde{X}$ refer?

Comment: @c_c_chaos the "schemification" of $X$, where we add points for all the closed irreducible subvarieties of $X$.

Comment: Then I think that the result is true: say $\tilde{X} = \operatorname{Spec} A$, where $A$ is known to be a ring of a certain kind (depending on the context you are working in something like a reduced algebra of finite type over an algebraically closed field); then the subspace of closed points of $\tilde{X}$ can be endowed with the structure of an affine variety and agrees with the original $X$. But to be certain: With what definition of a _quasi-projective_ resp. _affine variety_ are you working?